# Dependence of current on a network

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, potential, voltage

[image]

The square shown is a random network which consists of voltage sources and resistances. We measure the potentials of our points of interest as $V_0$ and $0$. Now,in this disconnected state,if we add a voltage source $V_0$ with the same polarity as of the points, why will the current flowing through the battery be $0$? How can we think of it intuitively or rigorously?

Comment: where is the battery in the random network? ... please add it to the diagram

Comment: @jsotola, from the Thevenin theorem, it doesn't matter where the internal source is. We can just use the Thevenin equivalent circuit.

Answer (score 0):

### A problem

Your question is interesting and relevant because this phenomenon is the basis of bridge circuits, transistor bootstrapping circuits, op-amp non-inverting circuits, etc. I want to answer you by accompanying my explanations with CircuitLab schematics. But there is a problem in this section - there is no CircuitLab tool here. So I will only answer you verbally in a few sentences until the problem is solved.

### The answer

If you connect a voltage source with the same voltage Vo and the same polarity to your source with voltage Vo in the "box", they will be oppositely connected in the loop. As a result, their voltages will be subtracted, the resulting voltage will be 0 V, and no current will flow in the circuit.